# Eclipse sending wrong project to github

Tags: eclipse, git, github, repository

I have github set on Eclipse and have used it before.
For some reason I am pushing the wrong project to my github account, which was my previous one and I have no idea why. I already tried to redo everything, but it is still pushing my old project.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and clone again your GitHub project, importing it (again) in a fresh Eclipse workspace, as show in [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGit/article.html#github_clone):

> Copy the URL from Github and select in Eclipse from the menu the File → Import → Git → Projects from Git
>
> Eclipse fills out most of the fields based on the URL in the clipboard. Enter your user and password to be able to push to Github.

Then a push should push your changes back to that same GitHub repo.